# wordpress how to replace url /bar with foo/bar for custom post type

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, slug, rewrite-rules

In my wp site there is a custom post type movies.i used cpt plugin to create it.
so if i have a post with title `zootopia` it's url appear as ,

`http://localhost/mysite/movie/zootopia/`

however i want to change this url to

`http://localhost/mysite/parent/movie/zootopia/`.so when i click view post i want this url to appear in address bar

so i want to replace url `/movie/` to `/parent/movie/`

i tried with `add_rewrite_rule` function

```
add_action('init', 'add_actor_url');
function add_actor_url()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( '^movie/([^/]*)', 'parent/movie/$matches[1]', 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

but this doesn't work.it doesn't replace url `http://localhost/mysite/movie/zootopia/` to `http://localhost/mysite/parent/movie/zootopia/`

is it really possible.if it's not then is there any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the slug to literally `parent/movie`. If you're doing it in code you set the `'rewrite' => 'slug'` argument to `'parent/movie'`. If it's in a plugin it would depend on the plugin, but there should be a setting for "slug" or similar.

Comment: but my post type is movie.so how can i set slug as parent/movie custom post type plugin support slug changes but without `/`

Comment: Then your issue is a support issue with the plugin developers. `/` is supported in code, so the plugin is over-aggressively sanitising the field. Note that the *name* is not the same as the *slug*.